# Given a list of names, search through a text file, save entire line where name is found into a new variable

Tags: python

Searching for names in an unstructured text file and grabbing their affiliation.

New to programming: Given a list of names, I want to search through a text file. Once a name is found, I want to grab the entire line and save it to a new variable. Then I want to split that variable left and right of the first comma and save into a two new variables (name and affiliation). I'm not sure if this is the most efficient way of doing it and I am stuck on getting a code that works.

To begin I tried to print out each line that found a match.

```
def search_for_lines(filename):
    with open(filename, 'r', encoding="utf8") as f:
        for i in range(0, len(full_name)):
            for line in f:
                if full_name[i] in line:
                    print(line)
```

My output is only one line containing the first name in the list, so I assume the logic with the nested for loops are off. Please help me understand what's going on?

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1):

For each line, check if it includes the name. If it does, save the line. For each saved line, split it into name and affiliation. This assumes that `full_name` is a list of strings.

```py
saved_lines = []
with open(filename, 'r', encoding='utf8') as f:

    for line in f:
        for full in full_name:
            if full in line:
                saved_lines.append(line)

for line in saved_lines:
    name, affiliation = line.split(',')
```

Comment: @Gabriella This assumes either that lines don't contain two of the names in the list of names, or that when they do, the line is counted twice. Note that even if a the text file is constructed assuming a line per person, potentially a name in the list can be a sub-string of another name, or some other part of the string.

Comment: Thanks for your help. I checked the output by printing out the lines without saving. It sometimes pulling lines that do not contain a name and repetitively prints the same line out (I assume the length of my list around 2000). Your code makes sense, I'm not sure what's wrong? Sorry did not refresh. Yes, the text file does not have lines where two names exist.

Answer (score 0):

From your description, and comment, I understood that a name from the list of names (variable `full_name`) can appear in many lines and that you want to collect from all those lines the affiliations that correspond to that name. You can do that with a dictionary that associates to each name the list of its affiliations.

File `affil.py`:

```
file_name = 'affil.txt'
full_name = ['A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'B']

from collections import defaultdict
name_to_affiliation = defaultdict(list) 
with open(file_name, 'r') as infile:
    for line in infile:
        if ',' in line and any(name in line for name in full_name): # * See below
            name, affiliation = line.strip('\n').split(',')[:2]
            name_to_affiliation[name].append(affiliation)
print(name_to_affiliation)
```

For `names = ['A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'B']` and the input file `affil.txt` containing:

```
A,aaa
A,a1a1a1
B,bbbbbbbbb
A,a2a3a3
C,6533
```

it creates (run `python affil.py`) the dictionary

```
name_to_affiliation = {'A': ['aaa', 'a1a1a1', 'a2a3a3'], 'B': ['bbbbbbbbb'], 'C': ['6533']}
```

It prints

```
defaultdict(<class 'list'>, {'A': ['aaa', 'a1a1a1', 'a2a3a3'], 'B': ['bbbbbbbbb'], 'C': ['6533']})
```

- The condition `any(name in line for name in full_name)` is nice to read, but maybe the implementation of the Python interpreter will not be as efficient as this can be when the lines are very long. See [Aho-Corasick algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Aho%E2%80%93Corasick_algorithm) to make the simultaneous matching of many strings more efficient. See [pyahocorasick](https://pypi.org/project/pyahocorasick/) for a Python library that implements this algorithm.
- The condition `',' in line` means that we process only lines that contain some of the names in `full_name` and that also have a comma. If such line doesn't have a comma, we are skipping it. You need to see if you want to do something else instead of skipping them and adjust the code accordingly.

Comment: Thank you for your help. I executed the code exactly except added in my file name, changed names to full_name since that was my original variable name, and added in encoding="utf8" to avoid an encoding error. The new error I receive is: ValueError: too many values to unpack (expected 2). Maybe I did not give enough information, what extra information could I give to be more helpful?

Comment: @GabriellaSpence In what line do you get that error? When I run it I don't get any.

Comment: @GabriellaSpence I added how exactly I am running the script.

Comment: on the line: name, affliation = line.strip('\n').split(','). My name vector has a length of 2593. The text file I am using has 7819 lines. Is it that the file is too big?

Comment: @GabriellaSpence It looks like in some of the lines in your input file a name from `full_name` appears, but there is not ',' in that line. For that reason `split(',')` does, produce two strings, but only one, the full line. Then it doesn't have two objects to give to the two variables `name` and `affiliation`. I added a condition to the `if` to skip those lines. You will need to decide what to do with those lines, if you want to skip or do something else.

Comment: I get the same error. I tried printing out the lines that do not meet the if condition you added in. It prints out paragraphs with no names in it and then some lines with names in it that have commas. I think something is wrong with reading in the text file?

Comment: I think I know the problem. I looked through the file and some of the lines have multiple commas. The affiliation is after the first comma. Is there a way to use the split function so that it stores name to the right of the first comma and affiliation in between the first and second comma when a second comma exists?

Comment: @GabriellaSpence Yes, added that. You can do `name, affiliation = line.strip('\n').split(',')[:2]` to take only the first two pieces separated by the comma(s) to be `name` and `affiliation`.

Comment: @GabriellaSpence Everything is possible, the question is what exactly do you want to do? Does the text file has unique affiliation? If yes, then the dictionary will match names with one-element lists of affiliations. If not, then what do you want to say is the unique affiliation? The first one found? The last one? Other choice?

Comment: Thanks for all your help. I actually got it all figured out now!